# Use AWS CDK to spin up pull request review apps in Fargate?

Tags: aws-fargate, aws-cdk

i have a rails app and am trying to replicate heroku's review app feature (when you open a PR in github, heroku spins up an instance of your app with that code)

cdk + ecr + fargate seems to be an ideal way to do this. i'm building and pushing PR images to ECR and tagging them, and am able to stand up my app in fargate with the cdk, but now am stuck on how to actually orchestrate the spinning up of multiple unique fargate clusters.

i've tried exporting the git revision and having that persist as part of a naming convention like so --

```
const revision = process.env.REVISION;

const app = new cdk.App();
new myAppFargate(app, 'myApp-' + revision);
```

and running `cdk deploy myApp-$revision`
(and subsequently `cdk destroy myApp-$revision` when cleaning up)

this seems...not the best! it works okay locally but ideally i would want codebuild or travis-ci running this -- on the cdk side, it seems extremely brittle.

anyone have a better way to do this? thanks!